# How to hook in a custom query to the loop with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I want to create a loop and query posts by their author role. And display the results of a search term based on the authors role.

I've tried creating a function to alter the query's where clause:

```
                    $ids = get_users(
            array(
                'role'   => 'administrator' ,
                'fields' => 'ID'
                )
        );


        $query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'author__in' => $ids,
            )
        );


            // If the query has data
            if($query->have_posts() ) :

                    // Post loop
                    while ($query->have_posts() ) : 

                        // Setup post data
                        $query->the_post();
                        ?>

                        <!-- Do HTML markup and template tags here, eg. the_content(), the_title() etc.. -->
                        <h1>You're a post from administrator - <?php the_title(); ?></h1>


                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' ); ?>

                        <?php
                    endwhile;

            // End "If the query has data"
            endif;
```

I'm trying to add a WP_Query to the loop but this is where I get stuck with the results not getting filtered by role so I'm fairly certain I must be implementing this wrong - this is the first time I've tried to do something like this so sorry if it's a dump question but I can't find an answer to my question so if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be amazing!

Any advice welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [posts_where](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where)
 hook.

**UPDATE:**

Why don't you use the default WP_Query [author](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) arg instead hook.
You query will be :

```
$ids = get_users(
    array(
        'role'   => 'administrator' ,
        'fields' => 'ID'
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'author__in' => $ids,
    )
);
```

Comment: I've just updated my question - This 'posts_where' looks like exactly what I'm after but I think I'm implementing it wrong as I'm still getting no results ... I'll read up and see if I can spot my error

Comment: I have updated my comment, based on new information :)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after - I've updated my question as I still can't get it to work so wondering if I've done something stupid

Comment: You can see the live version here but it might just make things more complicated atm as this is totally unstyled - http://www.glampingfinder.co.uk/?s=england

This is an example of searching for 'England' ... theres lots of posts in England but only one posted from an administrator role type 'administrator test'.

Hope thats clear!

Comment: You should use `author__in` instead `author`, because `author` expects integer, while `author__in` expects an array.
Updated my comment again :)

Comment: Almost working exactly how I want - the results are now showing only from the 'administrator' user role .... however my original search term is ignored so if I have two posts from the 'administrator' role, one was tagged England and the other not and then did a search for 'England' it is currently displaying both posts and not just one. That's kind of a different problem however so thanks a lot for your help here!

Comment: Well you can add additional question that describes in more details the problem. 
If this answer helped you, you should consider accepting it, so it will help other people facing the same problem.